# Using ArcPy to select buffer line by length?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, buffer, select

I created a buffer, then converted polygon to line (around a city block). I want to select the internal line. I'm thinking since there is no uniform way that ArcGIS labels the interior or exterior buffer line, I can use length to select the line I want by using an if/then statement. I have not been able to find the script command that simply selects a feature/line. Anyone know?

Comment: can you please illustrate what you want ? I do not understand what you want to select.

Comment: I created a buffer around a closed line, and then converted the buffer into an inner and outer line. I want to select the inner line by selecting by attribute: length. Thus could also be done by selecting the right record in the attribute table, but length would be the key.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are looking for.  If this isn't helpful, try editing your question.

> I have not been able to find the script command that simply selects a feature/line. Anyone know?

You may be looking for the [Select Layer by Attribute (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000) geoprocessing tool.